# Using agsXMPP , can it send images?

Tags: c#, http, xmpp

I found this lib here

http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/

hacked on this example here:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=346

It works pretty well actually but I am wondering if one could rig up a message thats an image that would show up in the others (google talk client) or some other client for display?  I poked around on the web, couldn't figure out definitively if this is possible...their site says the api supports XML-RPC, could that do it?

Just want to know im not going down a dead end for this functionality...if XMPP jabber even supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library seems not to support [XEP 0231](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0231.html), the specification that *"defines an XMPP protocol extension for including or referring to small bits of binary data in an XML stanza."*